# Simple But Slow Query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have this simple query that runs in 0.55s.

```
SELECT tr.*

FROM Tournament_Result tr, Game g, Tournament t
LEFT JOIN Tournament_Type tt ON t.intType = tt.intTournamentType

WHERE tr.intTournamentId = t.intTournamentId
AND t.intGameId = g.intGameId
AND t.strStatus = 'live'

ORDER BY dtmCreated DESC
```

All joins are keys, either primary or index keys. If I removed the left join "LEFT JOIN Tournament_Type tt ON t.intType = tt.intTournamentType", the query runs instantly.

So I figure it must be the "t.intType = tt.intTournamentType" join, but I checked and both keys are indecies. Not sure what to do here. I even tried direct join and its always the Tournament_Type table that slows it down. I even ran the "OPTIMIZE" command on it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Armin

Comment: Why the weird mix of implicit and explicit joins? It probably won't make a difference in speed if all indices are present, but `FROM Tournament_Result tr INNER JOIN Tournament t ON tr.intTournamentId = t.intTournamentId INNER JOIN Game g ON t.intGameId = g.intGameId LEFT JOIN Tournament_Type tt ON t.intType = tt.intTournamentType`  ...then remove the first 2 joining conditions from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: And please the `EXPLAIN` of your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Say no to old Join style !
The query  returns what you want ? I mean, you are doing a left join, but returning all rows in left side, so.. why don't select directly your table ? How neccesary is the cross join ? You will return repeated rows.. Can you show us an example of your data and the desired result?

Comment: Hey guys,

Thanks for the rapid response

I changed the query to 

SELECT tr.*

FROM Tournament_Result tr
INNER JOIN Tournament t ON tr.intTournamentId = t.intTournamentId
INNER JOIN Game g ON t.intGameId = g.intGameId
INNER JOIN Tournament_Type tt ON t.intType = tt.intTournamentType

WHERE t.strStatus = 'live'

ORDER BY dtmCreated DESC LIMIT 0, 20

The Tournament_Type table does not need to be LEFT JOINED. However, the upper query runs in the same speed.

Comment: Here is the EXPLAIN:

1 SIMPLE t ref PRIMARY,intGameIdIndex,intType,strStatus strStatus 1 const 381 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 SIMPLE g eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 prize_prize.t.intGameId 1 Using index
1 SIMPLE tt eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 1 prize_prize.t.intType 1 Using index
1 SIMPLE tr ref intTournamentIdIndex intTournamentIdIndex 5 prize_prize.t.intTournamentId 439 Using where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something missing in the query.**Tournament_Type**  table is  *LEFT JOINED* and

also *none of the fields* from  **Tournament_Type** table  used in any other join or in the SELECT

If you are adding one column from **Tournament_Type**  table to be shown in the result

```
SELECT Tournament_Result.*,
(select <<Col1>> from Tournament_Type where Tournament_Type.intTournamentType=t.intType)

FROM  Game 
inner join Tournament on Tournament.intGameId = Game.intGameId
inner join Tournament_Result on Tournament_Result.intTournamentId = Tournament.intTournamentId
WHERE Tournament.strStatus = 'live'
ORDER BY dtmCreated DESC
```

Comment: Wow,

That did the trick

Here is the query:

`SELECT tr.*, ( SELECT tt.strType FROM Tournament_Type tt WHERE tt.intTournamentType=t.intType) AS strType

FROM Tournament_Result tr
INNER JOIN Tournament t ON tr.intTournamentId = t.intTournamentId
INNER JOIN Game g ON t.intGameId = g.intGameId

WHERE t.strStatus = 'live'

ORDER BY dtmCreated DESC LIMIT 0, 20`

Comment: Its so weird to me that this query now executes instantly, even though it uses a subquery to select a column from the Tournament_Type table, yet when you INNER JOIN, it slows down.

Its not making sense why that is. Thanks for the help. The trick you mentioned worked :)